# mysql Rand() function cause unexpected multirow results

Tags: mysql, sql, random, mysql-5.6

When I try to get random row from table by id using `RAND()` function I get unexpected unstable results. The following query (where id column is primary key) returns 1, 2 or even more rows:

[image: query and result]

I tried next variant as well which produces same result:

```
SELECT id, word FROM words WHERE id = FLOOR(RAND() * 1000)
```

I found another solution for my task:

```
SELECT id, word FROM words ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

But I want to know why MySQL behavior is so unexpected with using so elementary functionality. It scares me.

I experimented in different IDE with the same results.

Comment: Simply add a `LIMIT` to your original SQL

Comment: you may also find [this soution](http://chapter31.com/2008/03/21/returning-random-results-with-mysql/#solution-3) useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is not unexpected. The [`RAND()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) function is evaluated per-row:

```
SELECT RAND() FROM sometable LIMIT 10

+----------------------+
| RAND()               |
+----------------------+
|   0.7383128467372738 |
|   0.6141578719151746 |
|   0.8558508500976961 |
|   0.4367806654766022 |
|   0.6163508078235674 |
|   0.7714120734216757 |
|   0.0080079743713214 |
|   0.7258036823252251 |
|   0.6049945192458057 |
|   0.8475615799869984 |
+----------------------+
```

Keeping this in mind, this query:

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE id = FLOOR(RAND() * 1000)
```

means that ***every*** row with id between 0 and 999 has 1/1000 probability of being SELECTed!

Comment: Are you able to explain how the per-row probability influences the SELECT outcome. Can a result of no rows be expected as well as 1+ rows?

Comment: @Martin I have emphasized the word _every_. 0 rows and 1+ are both expected. I have not tested but in theory, if you execute the above query 1000 times and note down all ids you will notice that every row is selected about 1 time.